# Question about \maketoks macros from cwebmac.tex

Tags: tex-core

Consider the following code from `cwebmac.tex`:

```
{\setbox0=\hbox{\toksA={1.}\toksB={}\maketoks}\the\toksA}
```

What does `\maketoks` macros do and how does it work?

The following is a complete example (reduced from cwebmac.tex) for pdftex:

```
\newtoks\toksA \newtoks\toksB \newtoks\toksC \newtoks\toksD

\newcount\countB \newcount\countC

\def\makenote{%
  \addtokens\toksB{\the\toksC}%
  \toksC={}%
  \global\countC=0
}

\def\poptoks#1#2|ENDTOKS|{\let\first=#1\toksD={#1}%
  \ifcat\noexpand\first0\countB=`#1\else\countB=0\fi\toksA={#2}}

\def\addtokens#1#2{\edef\addtoks{\noexpand#1={\the#1#2}}\addtoks}

\def\maketoks{\expandafter\poptoks\the\toksA|ENDTOKS|%
  \ifnum\countB>`9 \countB=0 \fi
  \ifnum\countB<`0
    \ifnum0=\countC\else\makenote\fi
    \ifx\first.%
      \let\next=\maketoksdone
    \else
        \let\next=\maketoks
        \addtokens\toksB{\the\toksD}
        \ifx\first,\addtokens\toksB{\space}\fi
    \fi
  \else
    \addtokens\toksC{\the\toksD}%
    \global\countC=1
    \let\next=\maketoks
  \fi
  \next
}

\def\maketoksdone{\edef\st{\global\noexpand\toksA={\the\toksB}}\st}

{\setbox0=\hbox{\toksA={1.}\toksB={}\maketoks}\the\toksA}
\bye
```

**EDIT**

Consider the following test.w (I disable `\startsection` intentionally not to set destination marks):

```
\nosecs
\let\startsection\empty
@* Example.
@c
@<Something@>;
@ @<Something@>=
void main (void)
```

Run `cweave test.w`, then process `test.tex`

1) via pdftex

```
pdftex test.tex
```

2) via dvipdfmx

```
tex '\let\pdf+ \input test.tex'
dvipdfmx test.dvi
```

We get the following errors:

1)

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): num1 has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
pdfTeX warning (dest): num2 has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

2)

```
dvipdfmx:warning: PDF destination "ii" not defined.
dvipdfmx:warning: PDF destination "i" not defined.
```

The conclusion is that this romannumeral thing is simply to set destination mark in dvipdfmx. Maybe it may be replaced simply to `num #1` like for pdftex and then all this romannumeral stuff will not be necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro `\maketoks` parses a token list variable `\toksA` and transforms its contents, using temporary `\toksD`, and also `\toksB` which accumulates the transformed material before delivery into final `\toksA` (`\toksB` may contain previous stuff too). Also in use a `\toksC` whose rôle is described next.

Notice that to analyse one needs to know catcodes of `|ENDTOKS|`, I assume `|` has catcode other and the letters catcode letter. Well no it seems that the loop must end before hitting `|ENDTOKS|`, hence it is assumed that the exit point is hit, which means (see below) that a dot must be found at some point.

A loop is entered. The encountered tokens are examined one by one. Notice though that the code is not a token per token analyzer per se, things are grabbed as macro parameter `#1` hence it seems to be assumed the encountered material has no braced material for example, and space tokens will not be seen (and are pruned).

1. if the token is a digit of catcode 12, this digit is appended to `\toksC` and `\countC` flag is set to numeric value 1.
2. if the token is not of catcode 12, or is of catcode 12 but is not a digit:

   a. if a digit was already previously encountered, then that (continuous series of) digit(s) is appended to `\toksB` and the `\toksC` is reset to empty and `\countC` reset to zero, and one continues as below.

   b. else if the token is a dot `.` then the loop is exited, and the accumulated data put into `\toksA` (without the dot). Remaining stuff is discarded. <strike>Notice that there is a stray space token here (no `%` after `\ifx\first.`), but apparently the whole thing is executed inside a temporary box, hence does not influence typesetting.</strike>

   c. else the token is appended to `\toksB`. It it was a comma, an extra space is appended. Here also the code has a spurious space token (no `%` after `\addtokens\toksB{\the\toksD}`), but apparently the whole thing is destined to be executed inside a temporary box, hence those spaces do not matter. Then the loop is continued.

In short the effect is that the part of `\toksA` until the first encountered dot is kept, (possibly the dot was even hidden in a `{.}`), the rest is discarded, and spaces are added after commas. I don't quite get it regarding digits, why are they accumulated in `\toksC` and not directly in `\toksB`, because in the end their fate seems no different from other tokens (which I assume will mainly be characters).

---

Igor has clarified in comments that the posted code differed a bit from the original one in `cwebmac.tex`. The original code indeed has special treatment for the parsed continuous series of digits, particularly it seems to create PDF links, with different syntax if compilation goes via pdftex or for example tex+dvipdfmx.

```
% standard macros for CWEB listings (in addition to plain.tex)
% Version 3.68 --- January 2016
```

One finds:

```
\def\makenote{\addtokens\toksB
    {\noexpand\pdflink{\the\toksC}{\romannumeral\the\toksC}}\toksC={}\global\countC=0}
```

and also:

```
\ifpdftex
  \ifx\pdfannotlink\undefined\let\pdfannotlink\pdfstartlink\fi% for pdfTeX 0.14
  \def\pdflink#1#2{\hbox{\pdfannotlink height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox
    attr{/Border [0 0 0]} goto num #1 \BlueGreen #1\Black\pdfendlink}}
\else\def\pdflink#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{\special{pdf: bc [ \pdflinkcolor ]}{#1}%
    \special{pdf: ec}}\special{pdf: ann width \thewidth height \theheight
      depth \thedepth << /Type /Annot /Subtype /Link
      /Border [0 0 0] /A << /S /GoTo /D (#2) >> >>}\box0\relax}\fi
```

The pdftex case uses `\pdfannotlink=\pdfstartlink` from PDFTeX and uses `goto num` and not the `#2` which has the TeX `\romannumeral` whereas the dvipdfmx case uses the `#2` for a conversion to roman numerals.

Elsewhere (in the definition of `\startsection`) one finds examples of how destination names are created:

```
  \ifpdftex\smash{\raise\baselineskip\hbox to0pt{%
%     \let\*=\empty\pdfdest num \secstar fith}} % bad space in versions < 3.68
     \let\*=\empty\pdfdest num \secstar fith}}% changed in version 3.68
  \else\ifpdf\smash{\raise\baselineskip\hbox to0pt{%
     \let\*=\empty\special{%
       pdf: dest (\romannumeral\secstar) [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ]}}}\fi\fi
```

All this to confirm that the parsing of digits done by the original `\maketoks` was indeed not gratuitous `;-)`.

I am not familiar (this is an euphemism) with the PDF specs, I can only conjecture that one can not use target identifiers starting with a digit or consisting of digits, and that either the `num` keyword, or the use of `\romannumeral` is a work-around. This is pure speculation.

Comment: "...digits are transformed via \romannumeral..." - the whole `{\romannumeral...}` is argument `#2`, which is totally ignored in `\def\pdflink` in pdftex

Comment: `{\setbox0=\hbox{\toksA={1.}\toksB={}\maketoks}\the\toksA}` in my question is equivalent to `{\pdfnote#1.}` in cwebmac.tex (I have reduced not essential parts to make the example code simpler)

Comment: `\pdflink` was omitted - for the same reason of making the code simpler - it is not essential (it may be simply replaced with the number - the resulting pdf will look the same)

Comment: about your first comment, you are right, but there is also a `\def\pdflink` which does not ignore the `#2`, if conditional `\ifpdftex` is false (I guess for `dvipdfm`/`dvipdfmx` or possibly for `dvips` then `ps2pdf`, this is beyond my competence). Sorry in advance but I can't correct my answer until possibly tomorrow for lack of time.

Comment: Indeed, the second `\def\pdflink` (which uses `#2`) is for dvipdfmx. You are right: digits are accumulated in `\toksC` specifically to store the number, which will be converted to roman numeral. BTW, do you know what for we use `/D (<roman numeral>)` in dvipdfmx's specials for pdf outlines? Is it some kind of depth level?

Comment: I removed the spurious space in my question.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko sorry but I discovered `cwebmac.tex` to answer your question ;-) and besides, I don't know PDF specification. For example I see `goto num #1` in the `\def\pdflink` for pdftex and I am left wondering if this does the conversion to roman numerals, as `#2` is not used. I see `pdf: dest (\romannumeral\secstar)` somewhere else, which suggests that target names are using roman numerals, perhaps pure digits would fool PDF, or one is not allowed to start a target identifier with a digit ? these questions should be obvious to users of `cwebmac.tex` but I am not one `:(`.

Comment: To clarify my last comment `pdf: dest (\romannumeral\secstar)` is again from a non pdftex branch, the pdftex branch uses `\pdfdest num \secstar fith` whatever that means.

Comment: Can we get rid of this `\romannumeral` stuff completely? Will `\toksC` be needed then? See **EDIT** in the original post.

Comment: `texdoc cwebman` brings up a manual which contains a section Hypertext and hyperdocumentation with the sentence `Thanks to Hans Hagen, C´esar Augusto Rorato Crusius, and Julian Gilbey for the macros that make this work.`, referring to the tex+dvipdfm way, and further ``Alternatively, thanks to H`an Thˆe´ Th`anh and Andreas Scherer`` for the pdftex way. Perhaps you could try to contact one of those persons ? or DK himself ? Also http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html has a link to a Russian translation of the manual.